# Install-OpenAM 11.0

Tags: openam

I'm trying to install OpenAM in CentOS and I am following the documentation http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/OpenAM-11.0.0-Getting-Started.pdf

But, in step 1.4, the installation process freezes. And the following message appears:

```
Installing OpenAM configuration store in /root/openam/opends
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by the JVM not having enough Permgen and Heap. For example - for tomcat you need setenv.sh to have:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS\
 -server\
 -Xms704m\
 -Xmx1024m\
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Comment: It is better to have a system with at least 3GB of free memory. The answer above is what the problem might be

Answer (score 0):

Check your JVM version. OpenAM 11 does not support 1.8 and will freeze at installation time.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this is the use of OpenJDK. It will work if you use the Oracle JDK 7 to build and run with. This is because the self cert classes are different between JREs. They also moved in the Oracle Java between 7 & 8 which is the cause of @AlexS observed errors.